# How to override the key search in a treectrl?

Tags: events, wxpython, keydown

i wanna know how to override the default keysearch in a treectrl.

When i bind a method to the EVT_TREE_KEY_DOWN event and call the selectItem method of the treectrl, it doesn't have any effect.

This is my Tree:

Test <--root

-Aero orea(EI)

-Blub(BL)

-Test(AX)

-123(45)

-Blib (LOL)

My intention:
With the keydown event i am concatenating a searchstring. when iterating over the treeitems, i split the names to get the content of the brackets(e.g.:"EI", "BL"...).
Then i check if the content of the brackets starts with my searchstring. if it is true the selectItem(TreeItemId) is called. But this won't work. It seems that the default search ist still working and is causing problems in my keysearch.

```
class MeinTreeCtrl(wx.TreeCtrl):

def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.TreeCtrl.__init__(self, parent, -1)
    root = self.AddRoot("test")
    self.AppendItem(root, "Aero orea(EI)")
    self.AppendItem(root, "Blub(BL)")
    self.AppendItem(root, "Test(AX)")
    self.AppendItem(root, "123(45)")
    self.AppendItem(root, "Blib(LOL)")
    self.searchString = ""
    self.lastKeyDown = time.time()

    parent.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_KEY_DOWN, self.OnTreeKeySearch, self)

def GetItem(self, match, root):
    item = self.GetFirstChild(root)
    while item.IsOk():
        tmp = self.GetItemText(item)
        tmp = tmp.split(")")
        tmp = tmp[len(tmp) - 2]
        tmp = tmp.split("(")
        tmp = tmp[len(tmp) - 1]
        if tmp.startswith(match):
            self.SelectItem(item)
            break
        item = self.GetNextChild(root, item)
    return False

def OnTreeKeySearch(self, event):         
    now = time.time()
    if self.searchString == "":
        self.searchString = chr(event.GetKeyCode())
    if (now - self.lastKeyDown) < 3:
        self.searchString += str(chr(event.GetKeyCode()))
    else:
        self.searchString = str(chr(event.GetKeyCode()))
    self.lastKeyDown = now
    self.GetItem(self.searchString, self.GetRootItem())
```

Do you have any clue?

Thank you and best regards
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of search i found my mistake.
This line was the problem:

```
parent.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_KEY_DOWN, self.OnTreeKeySearch, self)
```

First I need just the `EVT_KEY_DOWN` not the tree event for key down.
Second I binded the method to my parent not to self (That is because i did copy & paste :( )

This statement was really useful to me:

> A typical example of an event not propagated is the wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN.
>   It is send only to the control having the focus, and will not
>   propagate to its parent.

-- [EventPropagation](http://wiki.wxpython.org/EventPropagation%22)